# Should I remove node_modules before deploy with yarnpkg?

Tags: javascript, package-managers, yarnpkg

Since yarnpkg states that their installs are deterministic, does that mean that I can keep the previous version of node_modules to reduce build time even further?

Comment: Iam assuming the that you create a new npm packages, you want to deploy to yarnpkg ,before deploy **no ** need to remove the node_modules ,but dont checkit  node files to server,just simply create .gitignore file put into node_modules

Comment: @ex-zac-tly Where did you end up with this? Do you remove `node_modules` before deploy or not?

Comment: decided to not remove the node_modules folder without much extensive testing on build times, partly because there currently is no real need to improve the build time.